# retrieve width value with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to retrieve some values with JQuery but there is one problem for `width` value. I just test it :

```
alert($("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").parent().attr('id'));
alert("width :" + $("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").parent().css("width"));
alert("outerWidth :" + $("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").parent().outerWidth());
alert("padding right :" + $("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").parent().css("padding-right"));
alert("padding left :" + $("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").parent().css("padding-left"));
alert("border right width :" + $("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").parent().css("border-right-width"));
alert("border left width :" + $("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").parent().css("border-left-width"));
```

and I get :

```
j_idt14:universe_login
width :453px
outerWidth :463
padding right :8px
padding left :0px
border right width :1px
border left width :1px
```

but when I verify this values with firebug for j_idt14:universe_login id, I get :

[image]

So the width calculated by JQuery isn't the same as Firebug...any idea to explain that ?

Thank you

Comment: @kritya : it's the same returned value -> 463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh no...my apologizes everyone

my code just run some code AFTER showing these values and modify it, so behaviour looks like correct.

I displayed values on `$("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").parent().ready(function(){...}` whereas I had some forgotten code inside `$(document).ready(function(){...}`

Sorry again, problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

jQuery provides three methods to calculate width.

1. [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)
2. [innerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/)
3. [outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

What you need for width is outerWidth().

> Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding and border.

Comment: Yes I know that. I just not understand why firebug show me another values than JQuery...?

Comment: Because Firebug shows width of the element including the padding and border-width, whereas jQuery width() gives only the width excluding padding and border

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.outerWidth()`.

Comment: The numbers that jQuery gives you look correct. Can you double check the width of the elemet using the Firefox native inspector or chrome inspector?